# Configuring LAMP - Getting 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: lamp

I just installed LAMP server on Linux Mint 20.2. My website files are located in /home/larry/Site/foxclone/public_html. All files are .php files. Project name is foxclone.  When I go to foxclone in the browser, I'm getting a 403 Forbidden page, not index.php located in the project folder.

foxclone.conf follows:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName foxclone

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/larry/Sites/foxclone/public_html


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by remaking my foxclone.conf .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).